MongoDB: drop collection created with special characters
How do I drop the Mongo collection created with special characters?
Collection name: arpit^Crxcurrencies02
I tried:
db.arpit^Crxcurrencies02.drop();

Error:

ReferenceError: Crxcurrencies02 is not defined


Use db.getCollection() and then drop():
db.getCollection("arpit^Crxcurrencies02").drop()


